# C#'s lock() in Managed C++

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, managed-c++

Does managed C++ have an equivalent to C#'s [lock()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and VB's SyncLock? If so, how do I use it?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The equivelent to a lock / SyncLock would be to use the [Monitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.monitor.aspx) class.

In .NET 1-3.5sp, lock(obj) does:

```
Monitor.Enter(obj);
try
{
    // Do work
}
finally
{
    Monitor.Exit(obj);
}
```

As of .NET 4, it will be:

```
bool taken = false;
try
{
    Monitor.Enter(obj, ref taken);
    // Do work
}
finally
{
    if (taken)
    {
        Monitor.Exit(obj);
    }
}
```

You could translate this to C++ by doing:

```
System::Object^ obj = gcnew System::Object();
Monitor::Enter(obj);
try
{
    // Do work
}
finally
{
    Monitor::Exit(obj);
}
```

Comment: I'd consider http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369459/cs-lock-in-managed-c/7527111#7527111 superior in that it is both more in C++ nature (RAII) as well as closer to the C# lock keyword

Answer (score 68):

C++/CLI does have a [lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/lock) class. All you need to do is declare a lock variable using stack-based semantics, and it will safely exit the monitor when its destructor is called, e.g.:

```cpp
#include <msclr\lock.h>
{    
    msclr::lock l(m_lock);

    // Do work

} //destructor of lock is called (exits monitor).
```

`m_lock` declaration depends on whether you are synchronising access to an instance or static member.

To protect *instance* members, use this:

```cpp
Object^ m_lock = gcnew Object(); // Each class instance has a private lock - 
                                 // protects instance members.
```

To protect *static* members, use this:

```cpp
static Object^ m_lock = gcnew Object(); // Type has a private lock -
                                        // protects static members.
```

Comment: Removed 'dangerous stuff' with 'do work' to not distruct people. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: I'm not familiar with C++, how do you declare 'x' ? Thanks

Comment: Rules for 'x' declaration are the same as in C# as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx. In summary the guideline is:  - define it as a private object, if you want to protect an instance variable;
- define it as a private static object variable, if you want to protect a static variable (or if the critical section occurs in a static method in the given class).  Thanks for your question - I will enhance the answer.

Answer (score 2):

There's no equivalent of the `lock` keyword in C++. You could do this instead:

```
Monitor::Enter(instanceToLock);
try
{
    // Only one thread could execute this code at a time
}
finally
{
    Monitor::Exit(instanceToLock);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try Threading.Monitor. And catch.